# Find and Close All Websockets from Client

Tags: javascript, websocket

My Angular application dependency is opening websockets via [sockjs](https://github.com/sockjs) (but they are just normal websockets, obviously). I do not have access to the websocket objects, so I can't just call [close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/close) on them.

These open connections are interfering with some other logic.

How do I programatically find ANY and ALL websocket connections and close them?

[image]

Comment: Won't breaking those connections break your dependency? Maybe you can hook the websocket constructor before loading your dependency, and make it give you a reference aswell.

Comment: The dependency is Angular hot reloads for local development. It will definitely break, but that's fine since Angular doesn't give a way to properly turn it off.